# how to predict only one class in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

In case you want to predict only one class. Then first you need to label your vectors in such a way that maybe label all those vectors as 'one' which has ground truth 5 and 'zero' to those vectors whose ground truth is not 5.
How can I implement this in TensorFlow using python?

Comment: This doesn't sound like one-hot-encoding...

Answer (score 0):

while preparing the data you can use numpy to set all the data points in class 5 as 1 and the others will be set to as 0 using .

`arr = np.where(arr!=5,arr,0)`

`arr = np.where(arr=5,arr,1)`

and then you can create a binary classifier using Tensorflow to classifiy them while using a `binary_crossentropy` loss to optimize the classifier